# Changing The Button Text Of A Simple Button DevExpress

Tags: devexpress

I am adding a button to each row of a Grid Control. Under the buttons property of the button there is a property o called "Kind" this changes the image of the button. I want to not have an image but just text. Where do I set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your task properly, the [How to change an in-place ButtonEdit button caption in different rows of XtraGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E903) example shows how your task can be implemented.